# PyQt: Simplest way to make a CRUD UI for an existing database?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

In the least amount of code, how should I enumerate the (hundreds) of columns in an existing database table and create a table view that is coupled to the database with type-appropriate widgets in the table cells to modify the data?

I understand this used to be dead simple, thanks to Qt Designer's Database Connection Wizard, but it's been deprecated.

Comment: Try to use `QSqlTableModel` for your view. Viewing and editing table data should work out of box. Adding and deleting entries require some additional buttons and simple coding.

Comment: Thanks @PavelStrakhov, but I think you need to feed `QSqlTableModel` a model; and you'd need to write a line of `model.setHeaderData` for each database column.  Is there a way of telling the model it should look at the data and represent **all** the columns?  Furthermore, at the enumeration stage, can you consider the data-type of each column and delegate an appropriate editing widget?  E.G. a 'time' column gets a `QTimeEdit` widget.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way as it was said is using `QSqlTableModel`. 
Let's assume that we want to:

- view data and switch between tables
- edit data using appropriate editors, e.g. QSpinBox for integers
- insert rows
- and delete rows

Ok, first we need to get the list of all the tables in the database. This can be achieved using `QSqlDatabase::tables` method. Also I will use `QComboxBox` to show tables:

```
 class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QFrame):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
         QtWidgets.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)

         # Connect to database
         self.__database__ = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
         self.__database__.setDatabaseName('sqlite.db')
         self.__database__.open()

         # Create QComboBox to show tables
         self.__tableNames__ = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)

         # Create QTableView to show table's data
         self.__tableGrid__ = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)

         # Create table model 
         self.__tableModel__ = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self, self.__database__)
         self.__tableGrid__.setModel(self.__tableModel__)

         # Connect combobox signal to update model
         self.__tableNames__.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.__tableModel__.setTable)
         self.__tableNames__.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.__tableModel__.select)

         # Set the list of the tables to combobox
         self.__tableNames__.addItems(self.__database__.tables())
```

Now we already can switch between database's tables and edit the data. But the default editor is `QLineEdit`. We can provide others editors using `QItemDelegate` class. In `createEditor` function we can get the type of column from `QSqlField`. There is a shortcoming because at least for SQLite for the `DATETIME` it always returns `string` (but it is SQLite :)). Probably you should find other way to get the type.

```
 class SqlItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
     def __init__(self, database, parent=None):
         QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
         self.__table__ = ''
         self.__database__ = database

     def setTable(self, table):
         self.__table__ = table

     def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
         record = self.__database__.record(self.__table__)
         column_type = record.field(record.fieldName(index.column())).type()

         print(record.fieldName(index.column()), column_type)
         if column_type == QtCore.QVariant.Double:
             return QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
         if column_type == QtCore.QVariant.DateTime:
             return QtWidgets.QDateTimeEditor(parent)
         # etc.

         return QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option, index)
```

Also in the MainWindow we should create and connect the delegate with combobox to update table name:

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QFrame):
     def **init**(self, parent=None):
         # .....

```
     self.__delegate__ = SqlItemDelegate(self.__database__, self)
     self.__tableGrid__.setItemDelegate(self.__delegate__)

     self.__tableNames__.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.__delegate__.setTable)
```

And the last step is implementation of `insert` and `delete` functions:

```
 class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QFrame):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
         # .....

         self.__insertRow__ = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Insert', self)
         self.__insertRow__.clicked.connect(self.insertRow)
         self.__deleteRow__ = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Delete', self)
         self.__deleteRow__.clicked.connect(self.deleteRow)

     def deleteRow(self):
         index = self.__tableGrid__.currentIndex()
         self.__tableModel__.removeRows(index.row(), 1)

     def insertRow(self):
         self.__tableModel__.insertRows(0, 1)
```